Trying to find a scifi movie with an alien object being studied
It was a SciFi movie where there's an alien object/ship and people have set up these like... Poles or something around it and they are observing it, and I remember at some point they start playing music out of it maybe? I very clearly remember a scene that included mention of music, possibly classical, that either the object/ship was reacting to, or they were analyzing audio and found this music in it.
It's possible the object was white, and kinda DNA/stringy looking, but I'm not entirely sure on that one.
But yeah, alien object, bunch of poles around it, that part is very clear. I feel like I remember it being one person on the ground studying, and maybe someone else in space? But I'm not sure on that bit. If it's a movie I would have watched it between 2010-2020 I'm fairly sure. But maybe it was all some fever dream.
I know it's not Arrival

Your mention of the alien object reacting to music makes me think of Close Encounters of the Third Kind. Not posting as an answer as it's been a long time since I last watched it, and I'm not sure whether any other details match.

Yeah, it's not that one because I know I've never seen that movie.

Given that your memory is a little unclear I agree with @JustAnotherCoder in the comments that this sounds quite similar to:
Close Encounters of the Third Kind (1977)

The Yamaha beats back the simple greeting.
BLASTING OUT OF THE FLASHING MOTHER SHIP COMES ANOTHER SERIES OF NOTES
THIS TIME IN INTERVALS AND RHYTHM.




